# Restarting a game and reinstantiate objects

Tags: c++, class, object, instance, reset

**Introduction**

I am creating a small game in C++ and would like to create a function to restart the game.

First I am creating the object `player`. Then I have an if statement to determine when a certain key is pressed to call the `New()` method.

**My goal**

In that method I would like to reinstantiate an object of the Player class, so all variables will be resetted.

**My code:**

```
Player player;

//New game method
Game::New()
{
    player = new Player();
}

//Game loop
Game::Loop()
{
    if(keyispressed(key))
    {
        Game.New();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing pointer and non-pointer variables. `new Player()` returns the address of a dynamically allocated `Player` object. You cannot assign this address to the non-pointer variable `player`; you'd need to declare `player` as a pointer:

```
Player* player = new Player();
```

You also need to remember to release the memory previously allocated with a matching `delete`:

```
// player starts out pointing to nothing
Player* player = 0;

//New game method
Game::New()
{
    // If player already points to something, release that memory
    if (player)
        delete player;

    player = new Player();
}
```

Now that `player` is a pointer you'll have to update any other code you've written which uses player, to use the `->` [member access operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b930c881%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). For example, `player.name()` will become `player->name()`