# Restart a game and reinstantiate a global object

Tags: c++, class, object, instance, reset

This is a very similar problem to a question i have already looked at, answered here - [Restarting a game and reinstantiate objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5552796/restarting-a-game-and-reinstantiate-objects) .

I want exactly the same thing except my problem is slightly different in that the object i wish to reinstantiate is 'global' and is only ever created when the program first runs.

At present i create the new 'Player' after my #includes and before my function prototypes ...

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "Monster.h"

using namespace std;

string MonsterTypes[3] = {"Orc","Goblin","Dark Rider"};
//create a stack of 'monsters'
stack<Monster>MonsterList;

Player* NewPlayer = new Player();

int NewGame();
void SetupPlayer();
void SetupMonsters();
void MainGame();
void Combat();
int GetMonstersLeft();
```

Do i need to create an entire factory class just to create a single player? Obviously when i call the function 'setupPlayer' i could create the player object in there, but would i not then have to pass 'NewPlayer' to every other function, i was just wandering if there was a way to avoid doing that?

Comment: One way to "restart" any program, is to simply create a new process that runs itself, while exiting the original process. It will seem like the program starts over completely from the beginning.

Comment: Just call `delete NewPlayer; NewPlayer = new Player();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new player in `SetupPlayer`, and assign it to `NewPlayer`.

Since your global `NewPlayer` is a pointer to a `Player` object, you can simply create a new `Player` in its place every time you call `SetupPlayer()`, as follows:

```
Player* NewPlayer = NULL;  // Initialized when calling SetupPlayer()

void SetupPlayer() {
    delete NewPlayer;  // Delete the previous player (if any)
    NewPlayer = new Player();
}
```

Comment: Please note that with the code above you the enter the dangerous and magic world of *undefined behavior*. Beware of the monsters.

Comment: Because `delete`ing a `NULL` pointer is *undefined behavior*?

Comment: That's not the case, it is defined as a no-op [by the standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172232/is-it-undefined-behaviour-to-delete-a-null-void-pointer)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need dynamic allocation. You can just declare an automatic variable like this:

```
Player player;
```

and then when you want to reset it you can use:

```
player = Player();
```

Always remember that dynamic allocation is expensive.

---

What I would probably do, instead, is to create a "factory" function:

```
Player make_player() {
    Player ret;
    // setup ret
    return ret;
}
```

So that you can get rid of that global object. Don't worry about the performance of copying the object back when returning: copies are elided by a well-known optimization (return value optimization - RVO).